# Repeat geometry / body / object / shape in PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots, macros

I depicted a pentahedron by means of the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset
{
    plotOptsA/.style={surf,patch,patch type=triangle,shader=faceted interp},
    plotOptsB/.style={surf,patch,patch type=rectangle,shader=faceted interp},
}

% Plot pentahedron.
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            zlabel=$z$,
            view={45}{20},
            colorbar,
        ]          

            \newcommand{\Ax}{-1/sqrt(3)}
            \newcommand{\Ay}{-1}
            \newcommand{\Bx}{-2/sqrt(3)}
            \newcommand{\By}{-2}
            \newcommand{\Cx}{0}
            \newcommand{\Cy}{-2}
            \newcommand{\ABCz}{1}
            \addplot3[plotOptsA] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,0) (\Bx,\By,0) (\Cx,\Cy,0)}; % x, xy ground plane
            \addplot3[plotOptsA] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,\ABCz) (\Bx,\By,\ABCz) (\Cx,\Cy,\ABCz)}; % x xy plane
            \addplot3[plotOptsB] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,0) (\Bx,\By,0) (\Bx,\By,\ABCz) (\Ax,\Ay,\ABCz)}; % x, xz plane
            \addplot3[plotOptsB] coordinates{(\Bx,\By,0) (\Cx,\Cy,0) (\Cx,\Cy,\ABCz) (\Bx,\By,\ABCz)}; % x, xz plane
            \addplot3[plotOptsB] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,0) (\Cx,\Cy,0) (\Cx,\Cy,\ABCz) (\Ax,\Ay,\ABCz)}; % x, xz plane
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like

[image]

I want to efficiently repeat this pentahedron many times but for different `\Ax`, `\Ay`, `\Bx`, `\By`, `\Cx`, `\Cy` and `\ABCz`, but I do not know what is a good way to do this in LaTeX / / PGF / TikZ / PGFplots.

In Matlab, I would use the code

```
% Clean up.
clear all;
clear global;
close all;
clc;
format compact;

% Figure definitions.
figure;
ha=gca;
set(ha,'NextPlot','add');
az=225;
el=10;
view(az,el);

ABCz=1;
for yn=1:4
    Ay=-1*(yn-1);
    By=-yn;
    Cy=-yn;
    for q=-(yn-1):2:(yn-1)
        Ax=q/sqrt(3);
        Bx=Ax-1/sqrt(3);
        Cx=Ax+1/sqrt(3);
        pentahedron(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,ABCz);
        ABCz=ABCz+1;
    end
end

xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
```

where the function `pentahedron` is defined by

```
function pentahedron(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,ABCz)

X=[Ax;Bx;Cx];Y=[Ay;By;Cy];Z=[0;0;0];fill3(X,Y,Z,Z);
X=[Ax;Bx;Cx];Y=[Ay;By;Cy];Z=[ABCz;ABCz;ABCz];fill3(X,Y,Z,Z);
X=[Ax;Bx;Bx;Ax];Y=[Ay;By;By;Ay];Z=[0;0;ABCz;ABCz];fill3(X,Y,Z,Z);
X=[Bx;Cx;Cx;Bx];Y=[By;Cy;Cy;By];Z=[0;0;ABCz;ABCz];fill3(X,Y,Z,Z);
X=[Ax;Cx;Cx;Ax];Y=[Ay;Cy;Cy;Ay];Z=[0;0;ABCz;ABCz];fill3(X,Y,Z,Z);
```

, to repeat the pentahedron. Is it perhaps possible to construct some macro or a new environment in LaTeX to mimic this Matlab function?

Comment: I have removed some of the tags as they are not related to the question but maybe to the answer. However I think you should move to `table` solutions since as you encounter there is very little you can do about `coordinates` syntax.

Comment: What about a `\newcommand` with arguments and you pass `\Ax` `\Ay` etc as arguments?

Comment: @percusse What would the `table` have to offer which `coordinates` does not? Nonetheless, I wonder if this is really an issue. Repeating a geometry like this in Matlab is trivial. One just has to write a function. So I guess the question is how such a function should be written in LaTeX.

Comment: Then you can just plot all entries of a table with one command instead of reading line by line which you emulate here. I'm too biased to comment on matlab side of things. You can include your matlab function and we can translate it if you wish.

Comment: @percusse As per your request, I just added the Matlab code.

Comment: @percusse Is the z buffer issue btw also resolved by using `table` instead of `coordinates`? Since in the former case, one would have one object, and not multiple, and `z buffer` only works within one object, right?

Comment: Yes I hope so. But if the geometry is too complicated there is not much to do Z buffer is not really a strong point of TikZ/pgfplots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct translation of your matlab script can be as the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset
{
    plotOptsA/.style={surf,patch,patch type=triangle,shader=faceted interp},
    plotOptsB/.style={surf,patch,patch type=rectangle,shader=faceted interp},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xmin=-4/sqrt(3),
            xmax=4/sqrt(3),
            ymin=-4,
            ymax=0,
            zmin=0,
            view={225}{10}
        ]
            \foreach\yn
            [
                evaluate=
                {
                    \Ay=int(1-\yn);
                    \By=-\yn;
                    \Cy=-\yn;%
                }
            ] in {1,...,4}
            {
                \foreach\q
                [
                    evaluate=
                    {
                        \Ax=(1/sqrt(3)*\q);
                        \Bx=\Ax-(1/sqrt(3));
                        \Cx=\Ax+(1/sqrt(3));%
                    },
                    count=\ABCz                 
                ] in{\Ay,\numexpr\Ay+2,...,-\Ay}
                {
                    \addplot3[plotOptsA] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,0) (\Bx,\By,0) (\Cx,\Cy,0)};
                    \addplot3[plotOptsA] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,\ABCz) (\Bx,\By,\ABCz) (\Cx,\Cy,\ABCz)};
                        \addplot3[plotOptsB] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,0) (\Bx,\By,0) (\Bx,\By,\ABCz) (\Ax,\Ay,\ABCz)};
                    \addplot3[plotOptsB] coordinates{(\Bx,\By,0) (\Cx,\Cy,0) (\Cx,\Cy,\ABCz) (\Bx,\By,\ABCz)};
                    \addplot3[plotOptsB] coordinates{(\Ax,\Ay,0) (\Cx,\Cy,0) (\Cx,\Cy,\ABCz) (\Ax,\Ay,\ABCz)};
                }
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I hope it was supposed to look like this [image]

Comment: Your code, and thus your picture, contained some mistakes. I edited your answer, hoping to improve it ;). It's under peer review now.

Comment: @Adriaan Ah thanks, I wasn't paying attention to the formulas. But frankly your spacing habits are too much for my taste.

Comment: Sorry for that :(. Everybody has their own style I guess ;). Btw, I think there is still an error in `{\Ay,\numexpr\Ay+2,...,-\Ay}`, since the pentahedron are not drawn properly. One can see this by executing the Matlab script. That's how it's supposed to be. The `q` should be element of `-(yn-1):2:(yn-1)=\Ay,\Ay+2,...,-\Ay` where apparently you need the command `\numexpr`. Somehow this is going wrong. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Adriaan It's quite some time now since I used matlab. I don't have any working license but test if the loops are equivalent. I suspect that my quick numexpr trick is not sufficient. You can check it in an independent foreach loop in your document. Sometimes TeX don't compute integers properly.